# Angular 4 : How to disable lint warning to emit when running npm build command?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am working on an Angular 4 app which is being implemented using webpack (not a CLI project).
When I run npm start or npm run build , the webpack dev-server throws a lot of lint warnings like :

```
190, 13]: Identifier 'payload' is
228, 17]: Identifier 'payload' is
1, 34]: ' should be "
2, 42]: ' should be "
4, 28]: ' should be "
5, 37]: ' should be "
6, 33]: ' should be "
10, 16]: ' should be "
11, 23]: ' should be "
66, 23]: ' should be "
72, 23]: ' should be "
78, 23]: ' should be "
84, 23]: ' should be "
90, 23]: ' should be "
96, 23]: ' should be "
```

Is there a way we can disable all the warnings in the console? It should only show the errors if any

Comment: Have you considered updating to angular version 8 and/or migrating to the CLI?

Comment: Nope... We have lot of dependencies and migrating will be a bigger task

Comment: > disable all the warnings in the console? .. do you mean in terminal console? You can disable the rules in the linting tool that produces this .. Could be prettier or tslint in your case

Comment: @c_ogoo yes it is in the terminal console.  I have tslint. But how do I disbled it only for warnings ?? info and Errors only I want to display

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable "all warnings", because the linting rules don't have a severity as such - you can set / change rule severities in your linter configuration file (e.g. `tslint.json`).

You can however disable individual TSLint rules that throw individual warnings. Specifically for `' should be "` in `tslint.json` look for the rule `quotemark`. In your case it should say something like this:

```
    "quotemark": [
        true, "single"
    ],
```

Simply delete that line to rid of the warning.

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/quotemark/

Instead of disabling the rule, a better approach would be to update the rule to what you actually need, i.e. in case of `quotemark` you may want to consider to changing it to "double". Otherwise you loose the benefit of having a linter. However if you do that, you will get the opposite warning if you have single quotes in the code.

For any other warnings, similarly find the corresponding rule and remove/update it. It takes some effort, but the end result is a rule set that works for your project/team.

Another approach would be to go the other way and trim `tslint.json` to basics, and gradually add the rules you need.